# What to do if someone breaks a bone?

Tags: behaviour

What is the best first aid someone an do in events of fractures? I am sports physician - just wondering if there is a specific certification for something like this.

thanks

Comment: Depends on the bone.  Any good first aid guide should cover this, and in more detail than could reasonably fit in an answer.

Comment: Try health.se for this question

Answer (score 0):

When a person meets with an accident or a traumatic injury and the spot of injury goes numb or turns bluish, there are high chances that the victim might suffer a fracture. In case if you suspect that the person might have a fractured bone, then here are some of the things that you can do to help the person feel better at the earliest.

Once you are done accessing the other injured areas, the first thing that you have to do to treat the broken bone is to make sure it doesn’t move. Get anything that is strong and tie it to the place of fracture. This will stop the bone from moving any further. The next thing is to apply ice to the injured part and see if you can provide the person with some medication that can temporarily reduce pain. However, remember to rush the person to the hospital at the earliest.As for the course , I think [this one](https://www.wta.edu.au/first-aid-course-perth/) is pretty popular. You can also check St John's Ambulance as they are pretty much the standard in NZ and AU.

Comment: So a bruise is an indication of possible fracture??